# Pass argument to std::bind at run time to a dispatch Queue

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, std-function

I have trouble to pass an argument to my dispatch queue that takes a function pointer as a parameter. I have implemented a Dispatch Queue like [this tutorial](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/08/implementing-an-asynchronous-dispatch-queue/)

```
typedef std::function<std::string( const std::array<float, kMaxSamples> &)> fp_t;


class DispatchQueue {
public:
    DispatchQueue(std::string name, size_t thread_cnt = 1);
    ~DispatchQueue();
    //move
    void dispatch(fp_t && item); //Take the typedef defined above

private:

    std::string _name;
    std::queue<fp_t> _q;
    std::vector<std::thread> _threads;
    void dispatch_thread_handler(void);
    std::mutex _lock;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    bool _quit;
};
```

My std::function takes an std::array as a parameter.

Then, later in my code I add in the queue this particular job to process this argument.

`queue->dispatch(std::bind(&AudioRecordEngine::run, mRecordingCallbackImp.getAudioData()));`

The dispatch function is defined as:

```
void DispatchQueue::dispatch(fp_t &&item)
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_lock);

    _q.push(item);

    // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
    // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
    lock.unlock();
    _cv.notify_one();
}`
```

Maybe it is too complicated for this use case, I probably don't know how to do better.

I would greatly appreciate suggestion and help. I am stuck for quite a while.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
The problem I am facing is at compilation time:

no viable conversion from '__bind<std::__ndk1::__bind<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits, std::__ndk1::allocator > (AudioRecordEngine::*)(const std::__ndk1::array<float, 44100> &), std::__ndk1::array<float, 44100> > >' to 'fp_t' (aka 'function<basic_string<char, char_traits, allocator > (const array<float, kMaxSamples> &)>')

It seems that my std::function do not support the argument I am passing. The problem look like I do not use the std::bind properly.

Basically I would like to pass to my dispatch function the function pointer with the given argument.

EDIT 2:

The AudioRecordEngine::run is defined as:

```
   std::string AudioRecordEngine::run(const std::array<float,    __NUM_SAMPLES__> & audioData) {
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    LOGD("In the thread ID %zu  \n", this_id);
    //double freq = FFTNativeWrapper::fftEntryPoint(audioData);
    //LOGD("In the Thread, FFT analysis == %zu  \n", freq);
    return "from thread";
}


std::array<float, kMaxSamples> RecordingCallbackImp::getAudioData() {
return mData;
```

}

Comment: I have edited my post with the error given at compilation time. Let me know if still unclear. Thanks for you time. I am not sure if the argument will be passed properly to the dispatch function. It is quite a complex problem for me.

Comment: It would also help if you include declarations of `AudioRecordEngine::run` and `getAudioData()`.

Comment: `std::function` expects something that takes one parameter. Your `std::bind` doesn't contain placeholders, so it gives you a function (a functional object rather) with no parameters. Also, to invoke a member function (`run`) you have to provide an object of type `AudioRecordEngine` as the first parameter.

Comment: And how do you invoke functional objected from `_q`?

Comment: `getAudioData` or `getRecordData`?

Comment: I just saw there a char  and float type mismatch..I must have forgot something.

Comment: Oops sorry, i took the wrong function. Now the post have the definition of getAudioData(). And _q is my queue defined like: std::queue<fp_t> _q;

Comment: My placeholder is this one no?             queue->dispatch(std::bind(&AudioRecordEngine::run, **mRecordingCallbackImp.getAudioData()**)); I will review this, I think you put me in the right direction. I will check that. I need more info regarding the functional object. Thanks

Comment: @RemyS A placeholder looks like this: `_1` (literally). Look at some examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind What you highlighted in bold is a bound argument, not a placeholder. I recommend using a lambda instead of `bind` if you can.

Comment: I guess you don't need placeholders here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inside the implementation of `DispatchQueue`, functional objects of type `fp_t` are invoked as `fn()`, so `fp_t` should be `std::function<std::string()>` or `std::function<void()>`. There should be no `const std::array&` parameter.
2. `std::bind` should give you something that takes no parameters. Your `std::bind` is almost correct. When you want to invoke a non-static member function, you need an object. That object, in the form of a pointer or a reference, should be the second argument of `std::bind`:

   ```
   AudioRecordEngine engine;

   queue->dispatch(std::bind(
       &AudioRecordEngine::run,
       std::ref(engine),
       mRecordingCallbackImp.getAudioData()
   ));
   ```

   Be careful about `engine` life time.
3. Alternatively, you can use a lambda function instead of `std::bind`:

   ```
   AudioRecordEngine engine;

   queue->dispatch([&] { 
       engine.run(mRecordingCallbackImp.getAudioData());
   });
   ```

   This and the previous approaches differ by the moment when `getAudioData()` is called: in 2, the result of `getAudioData()` execution is stored inside the functional object returned by `std::bind`, in 3, `getAudioData()` is invoked just before `run` is called.

[Minimal example](https://godbolt.org/z/oa5Pec)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
The issue is that the dispatch function take a functional object is not of type fp_t.

no viable conversion from '(lambda at... to 'fp_t' (aka 'function<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > ()>') which is understandable. 

The thing is, I post in the queue via the dispatch and I do not want to lose the parameter im passing. Maybe there is problem with my design.

Comment: @RemyS, sorry, I didn't quite get what the problem is. The queue executes functional objects that can be invoked with empty argument list, i.e. `fn()`. What you pass to `run` is either stored inside a functional object (solution with `std::bind`), or computed when the functional object is invoked (solution with a lambda). Whether this is a good or bad design I'm not sure, but at least it should compile.

Comment: @RemyS, try to call it manually and be sure that `this` object still exists when the lambda is called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the code has compiled and my argument can be processed by the dispatch queue. The reason why it appears my run function not being called it that I have commented out the call of the functional object into the dispatch queue. It was my mistake. Thanks a lot @Evg
I have opted for the lambda, the code is shorter than the std::bind.  But both of them work well.